# Are these capacitors hooked up correctly?

Tags: electric-motor, capacitor

I have a single phase 220 volt Chinese motor that starts and runs but has no power and heats up very fast. I am wondering if the capacitors are hooked up correctly?

[image: wiring]

[image: wiring]

Comment: There's no way to know since the nameplate does not show the capacitor connections at all.

Comment: If it starts reliably and runs in the right direction , the capacitors are doing their job. Check for mechanical interference/bad bearings?